# Is there a WSO2 OpenID mediator?

Tags: openid, wso2, esb, mediator, authenticator

I know from WSO2 ESB documentation that there is an OAuth mediator:

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB450/OAuth+Mediator

Is it also possible to have an **OpenID** mediator in ESB mediation sequence?
I've searched WSO2 docs and googled, but found only 
this blog post about OpenID **authenticator** for Tomcat,
that is better placed in WSO AppServer, I think:

http://blog.facilelogin.com/2008/11/openid-authenticator-for-tomcat.html

The download link in this blogpost is broken, so second question is:

Is it possible to have OpenID authenticator in WSO2 AS?

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For First Question!

OpenID is about authentication (ie. proving who you are), OAuth is about authorization (ie. to grant access to functionality/data/etc.. without having to deal with the original authentication).

OAuth could be used in external partner sites to allow access to protected data without them having to re-authenticate a user.

So What is your use Case of having OpenID as a Mediator?

For Second Question!
Yes it is possible, Wso2 has OpenID as authenticator in carbon platform, please refer to [this](http://sureshatt.blogspot.com/2012/09/installing-identity-features-in-wso2-esb.html)! How to install it!

and if you wonder how to make use of SSO in carbon products Please refer to [this](http://sureshatt.blogspot.com/2012/11/how-to-enable-sso-for-wso2-server.html)

Comment: Thank you for answering, but my project has ended, so for me there's no need anymore to research this further.